# Extract a certain text element from webpage using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I appreciate some help for my attempt to extract weather data from the following webpage:
https://www.dwd.de/DE/wetter/vorhersage_aktuell/hessen/vhs_hes_node.html#Start
I'm only interested on the data in the

```html
<p><pre tag after the following h2 tag: 
<a id="doc395960bodyText3"></a><h2>Vorhersage  - morgen</h2>
```

I've tried several possibilities and read a lot of tutorials but without success.
My current code shows all `<p><pre` tags not only the one i want.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

page = requests.get('https://www.dwd.de/DE/wetter/vorhersage_aktuell/hessen/vhs_hes_node.html#doc395960bodyText3').text 
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser') 
#result = soup.find('pre', id='doc395960bodyText3')
data = soup.find_all('pre')
  
for text in data:
    print(text.get_text())
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get(
    "https://www.dwd.de/DE/wetter/vorhersage_aktuell/hessen/vhs_hes_node.html#doc395960bodyText3"
).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

pre = soup.select_one('h2:-soup-contains("Vorhersage  - morgen") + * pre')
print(pre.text)
```

Prints:

```
Am Dienstag bei meist starker Bewölkung zeit- und gebietsweise Regen, teils schauerartig verstärkt. Am Nachmittag von Südwesten her nachlassend, nachfolgend Auflockerungen. Höchstwerte zwischen 12 und 15 Grad. In Hochlagen 10 bis 13 Grad. Schwacher bis mäßiger Wind aus Südwest, im Bergland teils böig auffrischend.
In der Nacht zum Mittwoch gebietsweise Auflockerungen und niederschlagsfrei. Minimumtemperaturen zwischen 8 und 4 Grad.
```

Comment: Thanks, for this high-speed response. This matches exactly the expected result.